# Discovering disks order

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I Installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on a Lenovo ThinkSystem SR530 server.
The server has 2 volumes (disks):

```
lshw -c disk
  *-disk
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: RAID 940-8i 4GB
       vendor: Lenovo
       physical id: 3.6f.0
       bus info: scsi@0:3.111.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 5.22
       serial: 003519c89a2e87672cc0206411b26200
       size: 10TiB (11TB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ThinkSystem M.2
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@15:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 00-0
       serial: f4c08db9a5c60010
       size: 223GiB (239GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=772aa01b-e452-469d-9d9c-cf0822d4471a logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

/dev/sda (RAID 940-8i 4GB) is the data volume. 
/dev/sdb (ThinkSystem M.2) is the system volume.

I would to know how to substitute disks names to have: 
/dev/sda (ThinkSystem M.2) system volume. 
/dev/sdb (RAID 940-8i 4GB) data volume.

I tried to add `rd.driver.pre=ahci rd.driver.post=megasas,megaraid_sas` in the kernel cmd line but there is no change. 
Could you help me please?

Comment: You should specify the **actual need** for changing the device names.

Comment: The letter behind /devsd is based on 1st disk that is ready Sobasically the speed of the disk. We stopped using those deviece names a long time ago. Start using predictable names.

Comment: Although from Red Hat, this document describes these concepts: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/deduplicating_and_compressing_storage/assembly_overview-of-persistent-naming-attributes_deduplicating-and-compressing-storage